# Como criar um filtro com todos os produtos na segunda lista, exceto com os produtos que retornaram na primeira lista

Tags: c#, linq

Realizar um filtro com os produtos na segunda lista, exceto os que foram trago na primeira lista

**Lista**

```
List<string> listaProduto = new List<string>();
listaProduto.Add("Arroz");
listaProduto.Add("Feijão");
listaProduto.Add("Chocolate");
listaProduto.Add("Ervilha");
listaProduto.Add("Mostarda");
listaProduto.Add("Pão");
listaProduto.Add("Queijo");
listaProduto.Add("Abacati");
listaProduto.Add("Tomate");
```

**Primeira lista**

```
List<string> primeiro= new List<string>();
primeiro = listaProduto.Take(3).ToList();
```

**Segunda lista**

```
List<string> segundo = new List<string>();
segundo = primeiro.**produtosquenaoestaonaprimeira**.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o **Except**, bem simples:

```
    List<string> segundo = new List<string>();
    segundo = listaProduto.Except(primeiro).ToList();
```

Comment: Muito bom, exatamente o que eu precisava, obrigado.